# mpdf dynamic HTML headers not appearing after auto page-breaks

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I have a dynamically generated report PDF using mpdf, with HTML headers that are changed dynamically throughout the document. This works for all pages where I manually insert a page break and set new headers, but where the page break is caused by content overflowing the page the headers don't appear and I'm left with a blank space.

I'm using html tags to set the headers when they're updated:

```
<sethtmlpageheader name="page_header_<?=$profile_name ?>" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
```

I've tried changing this (e.g. adding a page="all" attribute) but it only makes the problem worse rather than better, in fact most of the possible solutions I've tried have caused more issues than they've fixed.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: no, it's still an issue. the only way i found to get headers or footers to appear even on auto-wrapped pages appears to be to use a global header or footer and set it once for the entire document, which means not using it to display page-contextual content

Comment: I have only been able to overcome this limitation by manually calculating where to insert page breaks - it's a bit crude from a pagination point of view but you can then set the headers and footers for the new page and they work correctly.

Comment: I fixed it somehow but honestly I don't remember what exactly the problem was, it's been quite long now. I just looked at my final code and it is using the same sethtmlpageheader tag with the same attributes. I'll try to take out some time to look into it and recall it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me (after removing the `show-this-page="1"`  attribute of the `sethtmlpageheader` tag) (it is a snippet from the twig template (the `category` variable is passed to the template from the parent one), but I guess it should work the same in other templating engines or vanilla html too):

```
{% set htmlPageHeaderName = "product-list-header-" ~ category.guid %}
<htmlpageheader name="{{ htmlPageHeaderName }}"> {# mPdf reserved tag #}
    <div class="product-list-header">
        <b>{{ macros.categoryHeadingWithParentsToLvl(category, "div", 0) }}</b></div>
</htmlpageheader>

<htmlpagefooter name="product-list-footer"> {# mPdf reserved tag #}
    <div class="product-list-footer">
        tel: <b>123 456 789</b>, fax: <b>123 456 788</b>, e-mail: <b>info@info.info</b>, web:<b>http://www.www.ww</b>
    </div>
    <div class="page-no">{PAGENO}</div>
</htmlpagefooter>

<sethtmlpageheader name="{{ htmlPageHeaderName }}" page="all" value="1" /> {# mPdf reserved tag #}

<sethtmlpagefooter name="product-list-footer" page="all" value="1"/> {# mPdf reserved tag #}
<columns column-count="2" valign="justify" column-gap="8"> {# mPdf reserved tag #}
    {% set categoryParents = category.parentsToLvl(1) %}
    {{ macros.categoryHeadingWithParentsToLvl(category, "h2", 1) }}
    <div class="productsList">
        {% for producerName, productsByEdition in productsByCategoryProducerEdition %}
            <div class="producerDiv">
                <h3>{{ producerName }}</h3>
                {% for editionName, products in productsByEdition %}
                    <div class="editionDiv">
    ...
```